# How to run a conda command inside singularity?

Tags: docker, anaconda, singularity-containers

I would like to run a conda command with singularity.
The command is:

```
singularity exec ~/dockerimage.sif conda
```

It yields an error:

```
/.singularity.d/actions/exec: 9: exec: conda: Permission denied
```

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils wget=1.20.3-1ubuntu1 python3.8=3.8.2-1ubuntu1.2 python3-pip=20.0.2-5ubuntu1 python3-yaml=5.3.1-1  git=1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3
RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py38_4.8.3-Linux-x86_64.sh && chmod +x Miniconda3-py38_4.8.3-Linux-x86_64.sh && ./Miniconda3-py38_4.8.3-Linux-x86_64.sh -b && cp /root/miniconda3/bin/conda /usr/bin/conda
RUN wget https://data.qiime2.org/distro/core/qiime2-2020.8-py36-linux-conda.yml && conda env create -n qiime2-2020.8 --file qiime2-2020.8-py36-linux-conda.yml && conda install -y -n qiime2-2020.8 -c conda-forge -c bioconda -c qiime2 -c defaults q2cli q2template q2-types q2-feature-table q2-metadata vsearch snakemake
```

What should I add to the Dockerfile? How would it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, from the top, trying to build an image from your Dockerfile results in:

> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
>
> - q2template

I'm going to proceed with the assumption that you meant to install `q2templates`.

When writing Dockerfiles you should aim to have the least possible number of layers
and the smallest final image possible.

To that end you should follow a few rules:

1. Never use several `RUN` instructions one after the other.
2. Always remove all cache, installers and other unnecessary files.
3. Do not install things that are not absolutely necessary.
4. Do not create identical copies of any files - use symbolic or hard links instead.

In your case all 4 rules were broken - you have 3 `RUN` instructions
one after another, you install Python 3.8 twice (once as a system package and once with
Miniconda), you perform no cleanup after the installation and you copy `conda` script to
another directory.

Now we can discuss Docker-Singularity compatinility.

Processes inside Docker containers are by default run as user `root`. This means `$HOME`
is set to `/root` and so Miniconda is installed to `/root/miniconda3` - in other words
inside root's home directory, which is only accesible to root, even if files inside have `a+rx`
permissions.

Processes inside Singularity containers are run as whichever user executed command `singularity`.

That means you have to install Miniconda somewhere other that `/root` and change its installation
directory's privilges to allow everyone to  have access:

```
./Miniconda3-py38_4.8.3-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /opt/miniconda3
chmod --recursive a+rw /opt/miniconda3
```

So the final `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    apt-utils \
    wget=1.20.3-1ubuntu1 \
    git=1:2.25.1-1ubuntu3 && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py38_4.8.3-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    chmod +x Miniconda3-py38_4.8.3-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    ./Miniconda3-py38_4.8.3-Linux-x86_64.sh -b -p /opt/miniconda3 && \
    ln -s /opt/miniconda3/bin/conda /usr/bin/conda && \
    wget https://data.qiime2.org/distro/core/qiime2-2020.8-py36-linux-conda.yml && \
    conda env create -n qiime2-2020.8 --file qiime2-2020.8-py36-linux-conda.yml && \
    conda install -y -n qiime2-2020.8 -c conda-forge -c bioconda -c qiime2 -c defaults q2cli q2templates q2-types q2-feature-table q2-metadata vsearch snakemake && \
    chmod --recursive a+rw /opt/miniconda3 && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    rm /qiime2-2020.8-py36-linux-conda.yml && \
    rm /Miniconda3-py38_4.8.3-Linux-x86_64.sh

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

With that your `singularity exec ~/dockerimage.sif conda` will work and display
conda usage. Unfortunately if you try to execute some of the other commands, eg.
`singularity exec ~/dockerimage.sif conda run python -v` you'll get an error similar to:

> OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/opt/miniconda3/.tmp58csqy_a'

because the Singularity contaienrs are immutable, except for mounted directories.

Furthermore `singularity exec ~/dockerimage.sif conda activate qiime2-2020.8` will fail with:

> CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to
> use 'conda activate'. To initialize your shell, run
>
> ```
> $ conda init <SHELL_NAME>
> ```
>
> Currently supported shells are:
>
> - bash
> - fish
> - tcsh
> - xonsh
> - zsh
> - powershell
>
> See 'conda init --help' for more information and options.
>
> IMPORTANT: You may need to close and restart your shell after running
> 'conda init'.

even if you have properly modified set up your shell (tested with Bash).

The only way I managed to make it work was to run:

```
singularity shell ~/dockerimage.sif
```

and then inside the container

```
conda init # Modifies .bashrc on your host machine
source .bashrc # Loads modified .bashrc
export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 # Sets locale to UTF-8
export LANG=C.UTF-8 # Sets locale to UTF-8
conda activate qiime2-2020.8 # Activates the environment
```

Links:

[Dockerfile on GitHub](https://github.com/Forinil/conda-qiime2)
[Images on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/forinil/conda-qiime2) (use tag `latest`, others may not work)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [this file](https://github.com/biocyberman/covid19/blob/master/singularity/covid19.singularity) to see how I run conda during build time, and this [wrapper script](https://github.com/biocyberman/covid19/blob/master/workflow/covid19_nextstrain.sh#L169) on how I use conda during run time.

Further more as of this writing in November 2020, `conda activate <env_name>` is a misinformed command. The better command is `source activate <env_name>`. I had to look into the source code to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

I think (in Singularity) its a matter of finding the `conda.sh` path inside the container and running it at the end of the `%post` scriplet.

Something like:

```
%post
    . /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/mamba.sh # finding the path of the conda env
```